# SQL split data from a column merge with data from a different table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got two tables `TableA` and `TableB`.  One of the field in `Table B` (`bar`) needs to be split as its several things separated by ',' and each joined to the corresponding (`foo`) `field` from `Table A`.  Both tables have the field `ThingID`.

I've managed to get it to a point where it combines the fields from both tables that I need using the below with much trial and error (`SQL` is not my speciality!).  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
;WITH A AS ( SELECT ThingID, Name, Foo FROM dbo.TableA ), 
      B AS ( SELECT ThingID, Bar FROM dbo.TableB)
SELECT COALESCE (A.ThingID, B.ThingID) AS ThingID, A.Name, A.Foo, B.Bar
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B on A.ThingID = B.ThingID
```

Edit :  Example of what I've got and what I need.  First what I've got.

```
TableA                        TableB

ThingID | Name  | Foo         ThingID | Bar 
--------|-------|-----        --------|-----
  1230  | Aname | x12           1230  | x,x1,x2,x3
  1231  | Bname | x13           1231  | x,x1
  1232  | Cname | x14           1232  | x1,x2,x3
  1233  | Dname | x15           1233  | x2
  1234  | Ename | x16           1234  | x0,x1,x2
```

What I need to output.

```
XLS FILE

ThingID | Name  | FooBar 
--------|-------|--------
  1230  | Aname | x12-x
  1230  | Aname | x12-x1
  1230  | Aname | x12-x2
  1230  | Aname | x12-x3
  1231  | Bname | x13-x
  1231  | Bname | x13-x1
  1232  | Cname | x14-x1
  1232  | Cname | x14-x2
  1232  | Cname | x14-x3
  1233  | Dname | x15-x2
  1234  | Ename | x16-x0
  1234  | Ename | x16-x1
  1234  | Ename | x16-x2
```

Comment: I've no idea what you're actually asking. Example data with expected output would probably help a great deal. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you provide a data example and your expected outcome?

Comment: I have updated my question with an example

Answer (score 0):

Your probably not going to find a satisfactory answer to your question because your schema is bad bad bad. You have multiple values in a single field of a record, which is really poor design, and now you want to split those values out and then join on them individually.

Your best bet is to just fix your schema so that you can do a proper join and use your RDBMS as an RDBMS.

Instead of something like:

```
+---------+---------+
| thingid |   bar   |
+---------+---------+
|       1 | a,b,c   |
|       2 | d,e,f   |
|       3 | a,c,e,f |
+---------+---------+
```

Use:

```
+---------+-----+
| thingid | bar |
+---------+-----+
|       1 | a   |
|       1 | b   |
|       1 | c   |
|       2 | d   |
|       2 | e   |
|       2 | f   |
|       3 | a   |
|       3 | c   |
|       3 | e   |
|       3 | f   |
+---------+-----+
```

Putting some effort into the ETL work to get this into a proper table schema will pay off a lot more than the wacky workarounds you'll find trying to split those individual records into multiple records.

If you are stuck with having to split them (because of access reasons or stubbornness) then it may help to research "Split to Table" in sql server. There are folks that have written functions and other workarounds to help out. They will be slow and unwieldy and you may break down into tears a few times trying to make them work.